# Proving this limit equals approximation to irrational number

Tags: limits, irrational-numbers

The task:

---

Function below returns approximation to $\sqrt5$:

F(n)

1. $r=2.0$
2. $for$ $i=1$ $to$ $n$ $do$
3. $r=(2r+5)/(r+2)$
4. $return$ $r$

Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}F(n)=\sqrt5$.

*I've found this kind of answer*:

---

At first, let's change $r=(2r+5)/(r+2)$:

$r=\frac {2\times r+5}{r+2}=\frac {2\times (r+2)+1}{r+2}=2\times\frac{r+2}{r+2}+\frac{1}{r+2}=2+\frac{1}{2+r}$

That sum from $1$ to $n$ means that: $r_n=2+\frac{1}{2+r_{n-1}}$(where $r_0=2$)

And now, to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}F(n)=\sqrt5$, (where $F(n)=r_n$) will be enough to write continued fraction of $\sqrt5$:

$\sqrt5=\lfloor\sqrt5\rfloor+\frac 1 q$, where $\lfloor\sqrt5\rfloor$ is a floor of number $\sqrt5$

$$\sqrt5=2+\frac 1 q$$
$$\frac 1 q=\sqrt5-2=(\sqrt5-2)\times\frac{\sqrt5+2}{\sqrt5+2}=...=\frac{1}{\sqrt5+2}$$
$$q=\sqrt5+2$$
$$\sqrt5=2+\frac{1}{2+\sqrt5}=...=2+\frac{1}{2+2+\frac{1}{2+2+\frac{1}{2+2+\frac{1}{2+2+\frac{1}{2+\sqrt5...}}}}}$$
$\sqrt5=[2;4,4,4,4...]$ or $\sqrt5=\lim_{n\to \infty}[q_1;q_2,q_3,...]$, where $2\times q_1=q_2=q_3=...=q_n=4$

Now, instead of $\lim_{n\to \infty}F(n)=\sqrt5$ we can write:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}F(n)=\sqrt5=\lim_{n\to \infty}[q_1;q_2,q_3,...]$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}F(n)-\lim_{n\to \infty}[q_1;q_2,q_3,...]=0$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{(F(n)-[q_1;q_2,q_3,...])}=0$$
Now if instead of $F(n)$ and $[q_1;q_2,q_3,...]$ we will write our values and count this equation we will get $0=0$, which proves that $\lim_{n\to \infty}F(n)=\sqrt5$.

---

That's what I've found. I am not even sure that this answer is valid. Any notices or suggestions about this answer would be really appreciated.(I mean if everything is valid, then just let me know, I might be that stupid) Thanks.

Comment: How about supposing a limit exists (e.g. $L = \frac{2L+5}{L+2}$) and then solving for $L$ to obtain $L = \pm \sqrt 5$?

Comment: Note also that if $f(x) = (2x+5)/(x+2)$, $|f'(\sqrt(5))| < 1$, so the fixed point is stable.

Comment: Good point. Also $|f'(-\sqrt 5)|>1$ which is an unstable fixed point.

Comment: @Gregory also if $L$ exists, then $L = \sqrt{5}$ because a quick induction shows that if $r_n > 0$, then $r_{n+1} > 0$, so $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} r_n \geq 0$.

Comment: sure. I forgot the OP gave a starting point, I was being too general.